# how to work deployd authenticating users

Tags: node.js, authentication, deployd

This is a basic question about authenticating. He appear when i working with **deployd**.

So, what i do:
Using *postman* (getpostman.com) send *POST* request containing
login and password.

> /users/login >
>   BODY - x-www-form-urlencoded - username: petya - password: 1

Now check my auth. For example send GET to 
`/eventresouce` inclusive `ctx.done( {user: me.username});` and i got

```
{
  "user": "petya",
  "status": 400
}
```

So how deployd recognized me without any headers? Or *postaman* send some headers anyway? Guess i don't know some essential :)

Comment: Check the cookies sent.

Comment: Thanks :) So, now i know cookie not send to server - Cookie just read from browser.And my fault that I thought postman not use browser cookies